# .NET dll dependencies not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, dependencies, .net-assembly

I was reading Uncle Bob's [blog about SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod), especially his book's excerpt about SRP - Single Responsability Principle, and trying to apply it using a real Console app.

[image]

To prove his point, Uncle Bob says : *"In .NET the GUI assembly would have to be built and deployed with the computational geometry application."* So we have to break Rectangle into two different entities, etc..

But just to be sure, I wanted to test that statement and put each of these objects into their respective assembly.

[image]

To me, Uncle Bob means that if ComputationalGeometry is a console app, it should not run unless being put in the same directory as Rectangle.dll **and** GUI.dll, right ?

In fact though, my Computational Geometry Application is running perfectly fine without GUI.dll in the executable's directory. It crashes without Rectangle.dll, which is obvious. So .NET is quite clever and knows that the draw() function is not called by the ComputationalGeometry application.

Uncle Bob would be wrong ?
Can someone explain me the point I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, based on `draw()` method signature the statement that GUI.dll is required is wrong if method actually not called.

If all assembly references are inside body of method(s) than that assembly is not required as long as methods are not called (or to be more precise JITed).

This is what happens in your case - you have `draw()` method which *signature* does not depend on GUI.DLL and method is not called. Since your code does not call the method there is no request to JIT it, and hence types used by *body* of the method don't need to be loaded. So GUI.DLL does not need to be present in Bin folder.

```
  // method signature does not refer to Gui.
  void draw()
  {
      // Method body refers to Gui.
      Gui.Canvas.Default.DrawRectangle(1,2,3,4);
  }
```

In more real case `draw` would have argument of some sort of GUI context (like `draw(Gui.Canvas canvas)` and hence `Rectangle` type itself will depend on GUI.DLL. As result *using* `Rectangle` class requires GUI.DLL to be present.

```
  // method signature refers to Gui.
  void draw(Gui.Canvas canvas)
  {
      // Method body refers to Gui.
      canvas.DrawRectangle(1,2,3,4);
  }
```

Comment: In your explanation, you seem to have confused area() and draw() functions. My app actually calls area() which does not depend on GUI, so JIT works fine, but I think I get the idea.

Comment: @SimonBudin could you please clarify which part is confusing? I'm not sure why talking about `area` method would be even interesting in relation to GUI.DLL (as `area` method  should not brings any more dependencies than you already have by using Rectangle type itself).

Comment: ComputationalGeometry app does not need to use draw() in the Rectangle assembly and works fine without GUI.dll being present. Uncle Bob's statement seemed to imply the opposite in .NET, i.e "ComputationalGeometry needs GUI.dll to function properly", which is actually false.

Comment: In my example, Rectangle.draw() method actually directly delegates a call into the GUI assembly, which is not what you seemed to say.

Comment: @SimonBudin I see... I tried to say "`draw`'s signature does not depend on GUI.DLL while `draw`'s *body* depend on GUI.DLL". I'll think about how to phrase my post better eventually. Added some sample code which may clarify what I mean.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere so I can improve my knowledge a little ? Thanks !

Comment: @SimonBudin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206321/clr-dependent-assembly-resolution-at-startup and especially linked from there http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30601&seqNum=5 is one. You can also read something like [How CLR Creates runtime objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx) which touches on the topic. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/ is good (despite 10+ years old) read on the topic of loading/finding assemblies if you want to go even deeper.